# ntfs bad clusters (chdsk /r)

Tags: windows, filesystems, ntfs

A `chkdsk /r` on a Windows XP NTFS system partition revealed bad clusters in a file. `chkdsk` reported "*bad clusters in file xyz have been replaced*" (translated).
The filesystem is stored on a plain SATA disk (no RAID).

Quoting http://www.ntfs.com/data-integrity.htm:

> If the error occurred during a read, NTFS returns a read error to the calling program,
>   and the data is lost.

Ok, I guess the file is corrupted... really?

Quoting http://support.microsoft.com/kb/187941/en-us

> When an unreadable sector is located, NTFS will add the cluster containing that sector to its list of bad clusters and, if the cluster was in use, allocate a new cluster to do the job of the old. If a fault tolerant disk driver is being used, data is recovered and written to the newly allocated cluster. Otherwise, the new cluster is filled with a pattern of 0xFF bytes.

What is meant by "fault tolerant" disk driver? A RAID system?
Is there any means to determine if `chkdsk` restored the file without data loss or do I have to resort to using a hex editor to search to file for a 4 kB bloc filled with 0xff?
I am pretty sure the file is corrupted and I can easily restore it from backup, but I would like to now if there is a definitive answer.

Comment: If you have a backup, then simply restore the file and compare with the one that chkdsk repaired.

Comment: Seems like the Microsoft documentation is incorrect: I found a zero-filled 4k block by comparing the file relocated by chkdsk with the restored one from backup (no 0xff filling). So my assumption was correct, the file is in fact corrupted.